# append <li> if list item count < 3

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to wrap every three < li > elements inside div and I did it. Now I want to count if there are less than 3 < li>  inside that wrapped div, and if it is less than 3, then append < li >
This is my code so far, I don't know why it's not working:

```
var divs = $(".footer-events .event");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=3) {
    divs.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class='item-wrapper'></div>");
}
if ( $('.footer-events .item-wrapper li').length < 3 ) {
    divs.append('<li class="event"></li>');
}
```

All I want is to add < li > to fill the remaining space if number of children is less then three.

Comment: Why would you wrap three `<li>` inside a div? This is invalid markup. They are supposed to be children of a list element (`<ul>` or `<ol>`).

Comment: _“I don't know why it's not working”_ - we don’t either, because we don’t know what HTML this is working on to begin with. Please _always_ provide a proper [mre] of issues like this.

Comment: `.footer-events .item-wrapper li` is not limited to one specific `.item-wrapper` element, this will select _all_ `li` elements across the whole document, as long as they are a descendant of any `.item-wrapper` element that is inside a `.footer-events` element. You should probably select the `li` that are in the _last_ `.item-wrapper` element here.

Comment: Also, you are appending only one single additional `li` there - but what if number in the last wrapper was not 2, but only 1? Plus, you are not appending this _into_ the last wrapper, you are appending it to `divs`, which means that last `li` would be a _sibling_ of the `.item-wrapper` elements, and not be contained _inside_ the last one of those.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to append `<li>` to some `<div>`, which is invalid.

Anyway: here's a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (just plain old js) of what you apparently need.

[**edit**] A [recursive and functional method](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ulstuffer-pojs?file=index.js) for this

```js
const uls = document.querySelectorAll("ul");
const createLi = () => Object.assign(
  document.createElement("li"), 
  {className: "created"} );
uls.forEach( ul => {
  const thisUl = ul.querySelectorAll("li"); 
  if (thisUl.length < 3) {
    let i = 3 - thisUl.length;
    
    while(i--) {
      ul.append(createLi());
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.created::before {
  content: 'hi, I am created';
}
```

```html
<ul>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>item1</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
</ul>
```

Or a bit shorter/recursive

```js
const stuffUntil = 4;
const appendLi = (root, reFillIfNecessary) => {
  root.append(Object.assign(document.createElement("li"), {className: "created"}));
  reFillIfNecessary();
};
const stuffIt = (len, ul) => len >= stuffUntil ? true : 
  appendLi(ul, () => stuffIt(len + 1, ul));
const stuffUl = ul => stuffIt(ul.querySelectorAll("li").length, ul);
document.querySelectorAll("ul").forEach(stuffUl);
```

```css
.created::before {
  content: "hi, I am just stuffing";
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>

<ul>
  <li>item1</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
</ul>
```